# Various \textcolor within lstlisting?

Tags: listings, color

How can you set various words in your lstlisting to various text colors?

For instance, I want the word "fail" to appear in red and the word "pass" in green.

I have the feeling there should be some easy escape possibility!?

### What did not work

I tried using the parameter

```
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
```

and then within the lstlisting

```
(*@\color{red}@*) fail (*@\color{black}@*)
```

But this has no effect.

Therefore, I've tried

```
$\textcolor{red}{\lstinline!fail!}$
```

but listings does not like nested lstinline within lstlistings.

### Complex solution

a not quite suitable solution is described in [\textcolor within lstlisting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115547/7635): it is intended for one color only, so I would have to add something like

```
moredelim=**[is][\color{red}]{@}{@},
```

for every color I use :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The escaped part is a group, so color command issued there are lost at the end. There is no official way to set a color globally but you can look here [How can I change the text color in such a way that the effect transcends groups?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72747/how-can-i-change-the-text-color-in-such-a-way-that-the-effect-transcends-groups/73024#73024).

Beside this you can try to set the color with [`\aftergroup`](http://books.google.de/books?id=rstheMEAf2gC&lpg=PA121&ots=TTZDXr9Wkm&dq=tex%20%22aftergroup%22&hl=de&pg=PA121#v=onepage&q=tex%20%22aftergroup%22&f=false) (but color of keywords will overwrite this settings):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\def\redcolor{\color{red}}
\def\blackcolor{\color{black}}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@]
#@\aftergroup\redcolor@include@\aftergroup\blackcolor@ <fstream.h>
void main () {
fail
pass
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for both advices :) Are you sure about the escape? I picked up the escape sequence `{(*@}` in the (old) lstlisting manual, and it works fine so far (mainly for labels).

Comment: Why does your example require xcolor? It should work just as well for the color package, right?

Comment: No I'm not sure about the escape - and after some test I think I mixed it up with something else. I edit the answer. And regarding the color: You didn't provide an example so I used Gonzalos as starting point. You can use color instead if you want, but I would prefer xcolor.

Comment: Perfect for cases where keywords do not work. +1

Answer (score 13):

One option would be to use additional keyword sets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
language=C++,
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=fullflexible,
keywords=[2]{fail},
keywords=[3]{pass},
keywordstyle={\color{blue!80!black}},
keywordstyle=[2]{\color{red!80!black}},
keywordstyle=[3]{\color{green!50!black}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <fstream.h>
void main () {
fail
pass
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great in my case, thanks (+1) If no answer comes up that is more flexible (for other people that might want to mark the same word in different colours), I'll mark this answer as accepted in a couple of days.

Comment: In this particular case, I prefer to use `emph` and `emphstyle` instead of `keywords` and `keywordstyle` because "fail" and "pass" are not keywords of C++.

Comment: Though this is a great answer, I accepted Ulrike's, since aftergroup is the more flexible solution and explains and resolves the core problem.