# emphasise certain parts in lstlistings

Tags: color, listings, emphasis

I'd like to know wether there is the possibility to change the colour of a single word in a lstlisting. I know you can set certain words or characters to certain colours in the beginning with lstset{...} and emph{...} or morekeywords{...}. But I'd like to change the colour of a certain word only once in the listing and not everywhere. To give a simple example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
     try:
          sources.add(ds[0x013, 0x1010].value)
     except KeyError:
          pass
     print(sources)
         
\end{lstlisting}
```

I'd like the first "sources" to be in another colour, say green or whatever, but the second "sources" should stay the way it is (simply black).

I tried to find something via google but haven't been successful until now. Here on stackexchange I've found similar problems but not really the same and so far no solution I could find would really fit to my problem. Does anyone have an idea?

Also, a small 2nd question: How do I emphasise a comma (Or make it a keyword)? Unfortunately, it is the delimiter for emph{...} and morekeywords{...} and I've tried quite a lot of variants (e.g. , or {,} and so on) but none of them worked so far. I know the solution to my first question may also be a workaround for the 2nd one. But maybe there is a more elegant way.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: you should show a small but complete example (starting with \documentclass) that makes it much easier to test a solution.

Comment: Another option is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125265/various-textcolor-within-lstlisting.