# Extra }, or forgotten error when using `\textcolor`

Tags: listings, lstlisting

I am trying to highlight lines in my listing and I keep getting an error that says: `Extra }, or forgotten $. ...`

I am trying to highlight :

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, numbers=none]
(*@ \textcolor{red}{
if (n == 0) {
          throw new NoDataException(LocalizedFormats.EMPTY_POLYNOMIALS_COEFFICIENTS_ARRAY);
    }
}  @*)
\end{lstlisting}
```

Expected output(in red color)

```
if (n == 0) {
          throw new NoDataException(LocalizedFormats.EMPTY_POLYNOMIALS_COEFFICIENTS_ARRAY);
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allow others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: Hi, thanks! I am struggling to make this even more minimal. @leandriis

Comment: [color a text line in a code {lstlisting}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144451/134144)  might be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis same error unfortunately: `Extra }, or forgotten $. }}@>`

Comment: That is never going to work, the lines in between will never be given as arguments to textcolor. Have you tried just `\color{red} ` and no extra arguments

Comment: If you meant like this: `\color{red}throw new NoDataException(LocalizedFormats.EMPTY_POLYNOMIALS_COEFFICIENTS_ARRAY);
  }` then I get the same error unfortunately @daleif

Comment: Then full example that others can work with as already requested

Comment: I am sure [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115553/167081) is what you want